# FSM doesn't work when I run aiogram with fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, fastapi, uvicorn, aiogram

I have a problem with **fsm** using **aiogram** with **Fastapi**. I ran the code from [aiogram_fsm_example](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py), but changed the long-polling to the Fastapi implementation. Here's the code I've got:

```
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

API_TOKEN = "here's the bot token"


bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

# For example use simple MemoryStorage for Dispatcher.
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


# States
class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State()  # Will be represented in storage as 'Form:name'
    age = State()  # Will be represented in storage as 'Form:age'
    gender = State()  # Will be represented in storage as 'Form:gender'


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    """
    Conversation's entry point
    """
    # Set state
    await Form.name.set()

    await message.reply("Hi there! What's your name?")


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Process user name
    """
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await message.reply("How old are you?")


# Check age. Age gotta be digit
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit(), state=Form.age)
async def process_age_invalid(message: types.Message):
    """
    If age is invalid
    """
    return await message.reply("Age gotta be a number.\nHow old are you? (digits only)")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Update state and data
    await Form.next()
    await state.update_data(age=int(message.text))

    # Configure ReplyKeyboardMarkup
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    markup.add("Male", "Female")
    markup.add("Other")

    await message.reply("What is your gender?", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text not in ["Male", "Female", "Other"], state=Form.gender)
async def process_gender_invalid(message: types.Message):
    """
    In this example gender has to be one of: Male, Female, Other.
    """
    return await message.reply("Bad gender name. Choose your gender from the keyboard.")


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.gender)
async def process_gender(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['gender'] = message.text

        # Remove keyboard
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

        # And send message
        await bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            md.text(
                md.text('Hi! Nice to meet you,', md.bold(data['name'])),
                md.text('Age:', md.code(data['age'])),
                md.text('Gender:', data['gender']),
                sep='\n',
            ),
            reply_markup=markup,
            parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
        )

    # Finish conversation
    await state.finish()


# my changes
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return "ok"


@app.post("/")
async def process_update(request: Request):
    update = await request.json()
    update = types.Update(**update)
    print("incoming", update)
    await dp.process_update(update)
```

But when I run that with uvicorn (uvicorn main:app) and send /start command to the bot, the backend throws this error:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/./main.py", line 124, in process_update
    await dp.process_update(update)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 257, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/./main.py", line 38, in cmd_start
    await Form.name.set()
  File "/home/oleh/projects/tg_bot_test_fsm/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/filters/state.py", line 56, in set
    state = Dispatcher.get_current().current_state()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_state'
```

As far as I understood: there's a state in the dispatcher that is not created somewhy when I use the dp.**process_update**() function.
When I run that with long_polling - everything works fine, but I need so much to run it with Fastapi.
Is there a way to set up the state manually? Or I just do not process it correctly?

**P.S.** I run it in the WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. **Python** version is 3.8.10, **aiogram** - 2.15, **uvicorn** - 0.15.0 and **Fastapi** - 0.70.0.

**SOLVED:** if you're using Fastapi with aiogram and trying FSM, you need to set state in another way, with state.set_state(Form.name) function. My working code of start method looks like that:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start', state="*")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Conversation's entry point
    """
    # Set state
    await state.set_state(Form.name)

    await message.reply("Hi there! What's your name?")
```

Comment: It would be nice if you answer your own question. Easier to find out for other folks looking for solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to set current context for Dispatcher

```py
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
Dispatcher.set_current(dp)
```